# Rsync reports files as changed when transferred from multiple users

Tags: macos, ubuntu, rsync

We have an Ubuntu server which runs Nginx for hosting webapps. We deploy to  that server by using a shell script which contains a rsync command. We only want to transfer files which have content changes (no metadata). But now when I deploy and another user has done a deployment before, all my files reported as changed. By this we can't see if only the latest changes are getting deployed (and if we are missing some files from a submodule). When i run rsync multiple times on my environment, changes are reported like expected.

Example:

```
rsync -rltz --progress --stats --delete \
--perms \
--chmod=u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX \
--exclude='- node_modules' \
--rsh "ssh" \
--rsync-path "sudo rsync" sourceDir user@domain:targetDir
```

Does anyone have any idea how files can be transferred from multiple users to a server only when there are content changes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the `-c`, or `--checksum`, option.